# Баг с именем файла в windows

Tags: windows, windows-8

**TLDR**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробности:
 Есть сервер на nodejs, которому в некий момент нужно сохранить лог-файл с таким названием: `dest = './log/'+id+'.'+(new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[TZ]/g, '.')+'log';`.
Получается нечто вроде `43121180808.2016-01-25.10:27:51.271.log`.
На моем компе с windows 8 при попытке создать этот файл:

```
fs.appendFile(dest, data,function(error){
     console.error(error);
});
```

получаю ошибку **ENOENT**. Путь правильный. При попытке вручную создать файл с таким названием, когда вставляешь его из буфера обмена - винда один раз ругается, а на второй и последующие ctrl-v дает сохранить файл. (как видите на скрине, у меня есть один сохраненный файл с таким названием, но когда я пытаюсь сделать такой же со свежей строчкой из буфера обмена - выдает ошибку).
В чем фокус? На боевом серваке с разновидностью пингвина на борту все работает, дело в винде.

Comment: 43121180808.2016-01-25.10:27:51.271.log - точно такой? С двоеточиями? У мну семерка отказывается сохранять файл с двумя двоеточиями в имени. С одним - сохраняет

Comment: @HermannZheboldov ага, я уже заметил, см. ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем имени файла:

> 43121180808.2016-01-25.10:27:51.271.log

Присутствуют двоеточия(`:`). Их использование для имен папок/файлов [в Windows не допустимо](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions), в отличие от Linux.

Замените двоеточия на что-то другое - например на дефис(`-`) или подчеркивание(`_`).

Answer (score 2):

Пока писал вопрос - нашел ответ. Внимательнее надо быть, еще внимательнее.. Если вы внимательно прочитали вопрос, то могли обратить внимание, что пример имени файла таки содержит запретные символы (а именно `:`).
Написать вопрос меня спровоцировало то обстоятельство, что заботливая винда при попытке вставить эту строку как имя файла модифицирует её *прямо в буфере обмена*, после чего на руках остается валидная в качестве имени файла строка. Но уже не та что была раньше. Вот и весь фокус.